# Pass data between jobs in chain

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to pass the return value of a job to the next job in the chain, or is there another easy way to pass data to the next job? Otherwise I would create a UUID beforehand and pass it to the jobs as a parameter, which they use to access a shared memory.

```
use App\Jobs\FirstJob;
use App\Jobs\SecondJob;
use App\Jobs\ThirdJob;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
 
Bus::chain([
    new FirstJob,
    new SecondJob,
    new ThirdJob,
])->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely without the withChain method should work. But you have to address retries and timeout.

```
        Bus::chain([
            new OnlyofficeProcessJob($spreadsheet, $key),
            new OnlyofficeDocumentJob,
            function () {
                ds('will run after finishing');
                // dispatch(new OnlyofficeDocumentJob) -> this though will not work;
                // Podcast::update(/* ... */);
            },
        ])
        ->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In your initial job, store a value in the cache. For instance:

```php
Cache::put('foo', 'bar');
```

2. In your subsequent job, retrieve the stored value from the cache. For example:

```php
Cache::get('foo');
```

This way, you can share data between jobs using Laravel's cache system.